# Primary Y Axis Scale not Working in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have multiple Axis Highchart but the problem which I have facing is that Scale is not working for Primary Axis , only Secondary Y Axis scale is taken as standard.

So, the Line is appearing really low and not visible.

I have tried using alignTicks: false but that didnt help.

The issue is that no scale is appearing at all on Y axis.

Code :--

```
$(function () {
var options = {
chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy',
    renderTo: 'container',
    alignTicks: false
},
title: {
    text: 'Job Status'
},

xAxis: [{
    categories: [],
    crosshair: true
}],
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {

        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Transaction Count',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
        }
    },
    opposite: true

}, { // Secondary yAxis

    title: {
        text: 'Time',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value} min',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    }

}, { // Tertiary yAxis
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }
    },
    labels: {

        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }
    },
    opposite: true
}],
tooltip: {
    shared: true
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'left',
    x: 80,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 55,
    floating: true,
    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
},
series: [{
    name: 'Rainfall',
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: []

}, {
    name: 'Temperature',
    type: 'spline',
    data: []

}]
};
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/TestQuartz/json/highdefault.json", function (json) {
    options.xAxis[0].categories = json[0]['data'];
    options.series[0] = json[1]; 
    options.series[1] = json[2];
    options.series[0].type = 'column';
    options.series[1].type = 'spline';
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
});
```

JSON :--

```
[
{
    "data": [
        "11-Aug 12:03",
        "11-Aug 12:45",
        "11-Aug 13:13",
        "11-Aug 13:53",
        "11-Aug 14:03",
        "11-Aug 14:33",
        "11-Aug 14:54",
        "11-Aug 15:17",
        "11-Aug 15:49",
        "11-Aug 16:07",
        "11-Aug 17:00",
        "11-Aug 17:33"
    ]
},
{
    "data": [
        2300,
        5412,
        25,
        2577,
        2897,
        2812,
        2443,
        2923,
        2790,
        2187,
        2945,
        23
    ]
},
{
    "data": [
        12.4,
        4.56,
        3.8,
        1.2,
        11,
        12.3,
        5.67,
        7.65,
        34.5,
        12.78,
        10.5,
        2.8
    ]
}
]
```

Regards,
Abhay

Comment: Can you post some code replicating the issue or some more information that can help us investigate?

Comment: Here is you code as a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqk826qg/1/. I hardcoded your xAxis categories and series data based on your json.

Comment: If I change your code to `alignTicks: true` I get: http://jsfiddle.net/nqk826qg/. So, what is your issue?

Comment: If I hard code it works fine . But if I pull from JSON it doesnt work . Did you do any changes ?

Comment: Is the issue happening while calling something wrongly from JSON ?

Comment: I think the issue is that your yAxis are created before they know the scale needed and so it does not render correctly. See http://jsfiddle.net/nqk826qg/3/.

Comment: Thanks . Is there anyway to get it working ? I am new to highcharts so dont have much idea on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is you have 3 yAxis and 2 sets of data. You are assigning `series[0]` to `yAxis[1]` and `series[1]` defaults to `yAxis[0]`. In any event, when you are assigning the data to your chart you are actually assigning the entire `series[n]` object to the `json[n]` object which is overwriting you yAxis assignments.

What you need to do is just update the `series[n].data` and not the `series[n]` object like:

```
options.series[0].data = json[1]['data'];
options.series[1].data = json[2]['data'];
```

See updated demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nqk826qg/4/).

Comment: Perfect ... Thank You